# Setting httponly in JSESSIONID cookie (Java EE 5)

Tags: java, servlets, cookies, httponly, jsessionid

I'm trying to set the httponly flag on the JSESSIONID cookie.  I'm working in Java EE 5, however, and can't use `setHttpOnly()`.  First I tried to create my own JSESSIONID cookie from within the servlet's `doPost()` by using `response.setHeader()`.

When that didn't work, I tried `response.addHeader()`.  That didn't work either.  Then, I learned that the servlet handled converting the session into a JSESSIONID cookie and inserting it into the http header so if I want to play with that cookie, I'll have to write a filter.  I wrote a filter and played with `setHeader()`/`addHeader()` there, again to no avail.

Then, I learned that there's some flush/close action going on in the response object before it gets to the filter so if I want to manipulate the data, I need to extend `HttpServletResponseWrapper` and pass that to `filterChain.doFilter()`.  This is done but I'm still not getting results.  Clearly I'm doing something wrong but I don't know what.

I'm not sure if this is at all relevant to the question at hand but no html document is being returned by the servlet to the browser.  All that's really happening is that some objects are being populated and returned to a JSP document.  I've sort of assumed that The Session object is turned into a JSESSIONID cookie and wrapped -- along with the objects added to the request -- in an http header before being sent to the browser.

I'd be happy to post some code but I want to rule out the possibility that my difficulties stem from a misunderstanding of the theory first.

Comment: Added some code formatting because otherwise it was a bit of an unapproachable Wall Of Text.  Might still consider posting sample code of what you've tried.

Answer (score 11):

Since the `JSESSIONID` cookie is managed by the servletcontainer, this setting is servletcontainer specific. It's unclear which one you're using, so here's an [Apache Tomcat 6.0](http://tomcat.apache.org) targeted answer so that you know in which direction you'll have to look for your servletcontainer: you need to set the `useHttpOnly` attribute of the webapplication's `<Context>` element to `true`.

```
<Context useHttpOnly="true">
    ...
</Context>
```

Also see this [Tomcat documentation](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/config/context.html) about the `<Context>` element.

Comment: The more I explore this topic, the more I realize how utterly ignorant I am about nearly everything.  I'm using JBOSS 4.0 but, from what I've ready, JBOSS is an EJB container (?).  I'm not sure what servletcontainer I'm using.  I'll have to post again when I've found out what my servletcontainer is.

Comment: JBoss is an application server. It uses Tomcat as servlet container and adds some EJB and other fancy JavaEE features on top of that. The EJB story is irrelevant here. This is a HTTP/Servlet issue. By the way, I am not sure if the old JBoss 4.0 supports this attribute... At least, the instructions are the same as for Tomcat.

Comment: It looks like not even JBoss 4.3 supports this, you'll need 5.0: https://issues.jboss.org/browse/JBPAPP-3088

Answer (score 5):

You can use this with Java EE 5:

For Java Enterprise Edition versions prior to Java EE 6 a common workaround is to overwrite the SET-COOKIE http response header with a session cookie value that explicitly appends the HttpOnly flag:

```
String sessionid = request.getSession().getId();
// be careful overwriting: JSESSIONID may have been set with other flags
response.setHeader("SET-COOKIE", "JSESSIONID=" + sessionid + "; HttpOnly");
```

Source : https://www.owasp.org/index.php/HttpOnly

I test it into a filter