# who sets the JSESSIONID Cookie Request?

Tags: cookies, jsessionid

Is the browser responsible to set the JSESSIONID Cookie Request? And the server responsable to set the JSESSIONID Cookie Response?. I'm doing some tests where the cookie JSESSIONID doesn't have the the httponly. Only I can see it in the JSESSIONID Cookie Response. If so, is there any way to force JSESSIONID Cookie Request httponly?.

Comment: jsessionid is set by web container, like tomcat. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2992473/setting-httponly-in-jsessionid-cookie-java-ee-5